# Ricci flow on non-compact manifold

Tags: complex-manifolds, kahler-manifolds, ricci-flow

Suppose $\omega$ defines a Kähler metric on a non-compact complex manifold. Does
the Kähler-Ricci flow equation always have a solution (for small $t$)?

Comment: Without extra assumptions, the answer is no even on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Then on C^n what condition will ensure it has a solution? Any reference? Much appreciated!

Comment: As you can see, I am from a different math background.

Comment: http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/academic/Ni.pdf looks like a nice survey

Comment: Thanks for the editing and the link. I took a look at Ni.pdf and also some of Tian's paper. It appears that the concern were mostly on non-compact but complete manifold. What about open manifold such as a domain in C^n or P^n. I am working on the joint resolvent set of some operator tuples.

Comment: If the initial metric can be extended to a complete metric on $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{P}^n$ with the right assumptions, then there is a solution but no uniqueness.

Comment: No, it cannot be extended to whole space. The metric is defined on a complement of a hypersurface. It has singularity on the hyper surface. An example is metric defined on $GL(k, {\mathbb C})$ but not on all $k\times k$ matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with a definition:

Definition of conic metric on complement of divisor: If we take $X^{reg}=X\setminus D$, where D is a divisor with normal crossings. Endow
$X^{reg}$ with a complete Kähler metric which has a type of singularities normal to each component of $D$; in local coordinates, if $D = (z_1,...,z_k)$, the conic metric $\omega$ is  quasi-isometric with the following model, $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{dz_i\wedge d\bar z_i}{|z_i|^2}+\sum_{i=k+1}^n dz_i\wedge d\bar z_i$$

If $D$ be a simple normal crossing divisor on Kähler variety $X$ with some type of singularities, like conic, cusp,...., then the Kähler Ricci flow

$$\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t}=-Ric(\omega)+\lambda\omega$$

has solution on non-compact and quasi projective, open variety $X\setminus D$ when $\lambda=0, -1$

Reference: Paper of Unnormalize conical Kähler-Ricci flow
Liangming Shen
http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7284

2. $C^{2,α}$-estimate for conical Kähler-Ricci flow http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2420